# contact process name in android

Tags: android

I am trying to get the process name in android by using the method "List allTasks = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();".

However i am not able to get the process name for the contacts. I got the process name for all other like for sms android uses process com.android.mms. but when i am not able to figure out what is the process android starting when user click on contacts.

Can anybody tell me what is the exactly name of that process or i have to use any other method for seeing the process for contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's called `acore`.